# How to run db:migrate from another rake task with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to call db:drop, db:create, db:migrate from another rake task and specify the database like the command "rake db:migrate db=test". That way I can call it for several different databases in a row.

But settings Rails.env = 'test' and then resetting it Rails.env to a new environment doesn't work.

But the above code always executes on the development environment (if i take out the development environment I'll get this error

How can I call these tasks multiple times and change the environment to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once ActiveRecord sets the environment you have to tell it directly to change the environment. So this will work.

```
ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.env = 'test'
Rake::Task["db:drop"].execute
Rake::Task["db:create"].execute
Rake::Task["db:migrate"].execute 

ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.env = 'development'
Rake::Task["db:drop"].execute
Rake::Task["db:create"].execute
Rake::Task["db:migrate"].execute
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use the test database temporarily, set the database connection to *test* and then set it back to the defaults when the task is finished:

```
Rails.env = 'test
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
Rails.env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"]
```

Comment: This works works for db:migrate and db:drop but create still trys to use development. Very odd. Instead I'm just running `rake db:create db=test` as a system command to make it work. Very odd. Appreciate your help @infused

Comment: interesting. although this works when you set it the first time if you execute the task again using a different Rails.env it will use the first Rails.env http://pastebin.com/wYRa8dSk. It must set the connnection and then reuse it. Going to dive into the code to see if I can get around this